# FET Gate Voltage Question

Tags: gate-driving, powermosfet

What gate voltage is required to turn on a power MOSFET to the specified Rds(on) at a given drain current?
Take for example, 1.5A drain current using this FET.  https://www.vishay.com/docs/78092/sqj974ep.pdf

Rdson is specified at Id=8A with Vgs=4.5V.

I believe that if I provide Vgs=4.5V and Id<8A I can assume the resistance is less than or equal to the max Rds(on) specified. I then use the graph in the datasheet to adjust Rds(on) for junction temperature, as the spec is at 25C.

Thanks

P.S. This is not a trick question. I'm reviewing analysis done by others, and they are using what I believe to be an unusual method that gives an unusual result. They go thought a complex process that results in requiring Vgs=6V.

Comment: There are different types of FET, JFET and MOSFET, what you link to is a **MOSFET**. The datasheet has the information that you need. "I need to know the gate voltage..." it does not work like that. You apply a gate-source voltage and that results in a certain \$R_{DS,on}\$. The MOSFET doesn't abruptly turn on/off. As it is, this question is unaswerable.

Comment: ehm. Load controls the current.  Vgs-Vt controls the RdsOn

Comment: Every bit of information about the MOSFET you are asking about is contained in the datasheet you referenced.

Comment: What is not being told is how is Id controlled and what your Vdd  and R load tolerance? If it is 3.3V =/-10% there is uncertainty

Comment: Your Assumption is correct but is that your only uncertainty?

Comment: Thanks @Bimpelrekkie and others for your comments. I modified the question for more clarity.

I think this is a stupid question, but I have people determining the answer to this question in an extremely complex way, that I believe that no rational person would use, and I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Worst case current is assumed to be 1.5A

Comment: *They go thought a complex process that results in requiring Vgs=6V.* I still see no requirement for \$R_{DS,on}\$ so it is still **impossible** to extract a requirement for \$V_{GS}\$. In a proper specification the maximum allowed \$R_{DS,on}\$ is given or can be derived from maximum \$I_D\$ with maximum allowed \$V_{DS}\$ or maximum power dissipation. If that is not in the requirements then whoever wrote the requirements you're reviewing needs to do their homework.

Comment: Note how that MOSFET only has all values in the tables for \$V_{GS}\$ = 10 V, I would not choose this MOSFET and use it with a \$V_{GS}\$ = 4.5 V. It can still be used but much more care is needed to check that the \$R_{DS,on}\$ will then be low enough.

Comment: Yes, we actually have Vgs=10 nominally, but the WCCA analysis house says that Vgs=6V is necessary. I personally think that 5V gate drive is sufficient as the current is much less than the specified 8A. I'm more concerned about the extremely complicated method they use, and what I think is an incorrect answer. I'm concerned they are using this same incorrect method for other analysis they did for us,  and therefore they may draw a wrong conclusion in a similar circuit. I'm also concerned that the method they use is so complicated that no one can understand it. Thanks.

Comment: Concerning lack of a requirement for Rdson, I agree. I think that Rdson is not a strict requirement, but the worst case value needs to be used when determining power dissipation and junction temperature. I typically use the worst case Rdson and adjust for anticipated junction temperature. I'm afraid that these people did not account for Rdson shift with temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this answers your question. I'm using the "typical" characteristic graph in the data sheet you linked and red-lining it for clarity: -

[image]

So, with 8 amps flowing and a \$V_{DS}\$ of about 0.4 volts, \$R_{DS}\$ has can be regarded as having a value of 50 mΩ. Maybe it might be as low as 37.5 mΩ if the graph were more detailed in that little corner.

Anyway, that's the values as I read it but, it will be subject to temperature variations and a manufacturing tolerance spread that is undefined in the data sheet.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the Rds(on) is specified worst case at Vgs=4.5, Id=8 T=25C, so you don't have to read a number from the graph. By the way, my max application current is only 1.5A, so Vds would be less. I think it is safe to use Vgs=4.5V or higher, adjust for temperature. I understand that the Rds(on) vs temp graph is nominal, so perhaps we need to add some tolerance for that. Also, the company I'm working with adds tolerance for aging. I always assumed that the datasheet characteristics are at End of Life, so I wonder about that.

Comment: @MikeMcDermott if you look at the transfer characteristic graph, it's always advisable to use a Vgs greater than the convergence point of the three temperate characteristics. 4.5 volts is  greater but only by a small margin. Below the convergence point you can witness disastrous MOSFET fails due to thermal runaway. Above the point the MOSFET always takes less drain current when it warms and hence does not suffer from thermal runaway. For ageing you'd need to contact Vishay or dig deep on their websites. I'm unaware that there is any significant ageing process involved here.